# How to make a input validation function in C++

Tags: c++, function, validation, input, crash

Like the function below. can we make the same input validation into a function which takes argument of the datatype we want to take input.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<limits>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int testing;
cout<<"Enter a number ";
while (!(cin>>testing))
{
    //Err explanation
    cout<<"PLease enter a numeric type data!"<<endl;
    //clear previous input
    cin.clear();
    //discard previous input
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
    Sleep(1000);
    cout<<"Enter a number ";
}

cout<<"Your number is "<<testing<<endl<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666047/c-input-validation)

Comment: You can just put the code that's described in the duplicates answers into a function, which takes the `std::cin` and the variable you want to extract as reference parameters.

Comment: Please can you show this in code. 

Comment: Have you found the answer in the link given by @Zig or do you still need the code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at very beginner level and the code described there was a bit complex. I know how to do input validation but I want to make it into a function